# getting task cancel error while trying to call web api endpoint (hosted in machine A) from machine B in one of the machine for entire domian

Tags: c#, windows, networking, webapi, latency

I have a web api app hosted over machine A which is called from various machine within a domain.

```
var data = await model.GetDataAsync();
// Throttle the number of requests returned
return Ok(data.Take(maxRequests));
```

Total number of result `data` = 300 which is huge result payload sending over `https` over the network.

Within entire domain all of the machine which calling above endpoint works well and entire result packet received well.

But there is one machine B while calling this endpoint fails to get result packet and entire task is cancelled after sometime.

Note - if we're trying to take only few request `maxRequests` (1-10) out if all data, then machine B able to complete the request and get the result packet.

Question is, what could be missing in machine B? Network Latency, etc. Any registry change ? any configuration change in machine ? Please suggest.